# docker over virtualbox cannot start

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a docker file that creates a valid image that runs on my Ubuntu 18.04.

For compatibility with other machines, I've tried to run the docker in a Virtual Box Ubuntu machine (and avoid any configuration errors that may occur).

my docker run command line:

```
docker run -id --net=host --rm --privileged --gpus=all --env="NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all" --env="DISPLAY" -e DISPLAY=:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -v /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -v /home/git/:/git --name nirge_sim nirge-sim:1.0
```

The base docker file:

```
FROM gazebo:gzserver9-bionic

# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics

# install Utilities
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apt-utils curl ca-certificates wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install gazebo packages
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
    libgazebo9-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install ros packages
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    ros-melodic-desktop-full \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
    ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control \
    ros-melodic-gazebo-plugins ros-melodic-gazebo-ros  ros-melodic-gazebo-ros\
    ros-melodic-simulators \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# final config for ros
RUN echo 'source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash' >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1' >>  /root/.bashrc
CMD ["bash"]
```

So this works on my Host, but not on my hosted host via virtual box.
the error is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: nvml error: driver not loaded: unknown.
```

Would appreciate any advice on this issue.

Comment: Given the number of Docker features you're disabling, and given that you already have a VM as an isolation layer, does it make more sense to just directly run your program inside the VM without also involving Docker?

Comment: You have a point, but I'd like to keep it on Docker for a fast reseting of simulated environment.
Also, it helps for later automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that one of the dependencies (Gazebo) requires a dedicated GPU, one that is not simulated as a part of VirtualBox.

`Nvidia cards tend to work well in Ubuntu`
sourced from [original site](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_b1&cat=)